# linq to xml duplicate namespace gives empty attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```
<ftc:XX version="1.1" 
  xmlns:ftc="urn:v1" 
  xmlns="urn:v1">     
  <ftc:YY>    
    <SIN>000000</SIN>    
    <Country>CA</Country>    
  </ftc:YY>
</ftc:XX>
```

this is the what i need to create. but when i create this, it shows empty namespace in the SIN and Country tag. i need to remove that. can anyone guide me?

this is the code which i use,

```
XNamespace ftc = "urn:v1";
XElement XX = new XElement(ftc + "XX",
  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ftc", ftc.NamespaceName),
  new XAttribute("xmlns", ftc.NamespaceName),
  new XAttribute("version","1.1"),

  new XElement(ftc + "YY",                    
    XElement("SIN", "000000"),
    new XElement("Country", "CA")
  )
)
```

with this, what i get is like this.

```
<ftc:XX version="1.1" 
  xmlns:ftc="urn:v1" 
  xmlns="urn:v1">     
  <ftc:YY>    
    <SIN xmlns="">000000</SIN>    
    <Country xmlns="">CA</Country>    
  </ftc:YY>
</ftc:XX>
```

but i need without this part.

> xmlns=""

Answer (score 0):

`SIN` and `Country` belong to the `urn:v1` namespace. Your document has a default namespace of `urn:v1` so all elements without an explicit namespace prefix will belong to that namespace.

When you created those elements, they were in the empty namespace, so that extra namespace declaration needed to be generated.

```
XNamespace ftc = "urn:v1";
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(ftc + "XX",
        new XAttribute("version", "1.1"),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ftc", ftc),
        new XAttribute("xmlns", ftc),
        new XElement(ftc + "YY",
            new XElement(ftc + "SIN", "000000"),
            new XElement(ftc + "Country", "CA")
        )
    )
);
```

```
<XX version="1.1" xmlns:ftc="urn:v1" xmlns="urn:v1">
  <YY>
    <SIN>000000</SIN>
    <Country>CA</Country>
  </YY>
</XX>
```

Note that since your explicit namespace `ftc` and the default namespace are equal, none of the prefixes will be generated as you expect. This isn't configurable on a per element level as far as I know.

Comment: Thank You @Jeff, yes I agreed with you. but in may case, I have to create like this..